# nasaworking on a way to travel faster than speed of light

Tags: space-time, nasa

even if they did how will time pass in that ship. Also that ship would require a infinite amount of energy to fight the drag.but what would provide the drag since in space there is nothing to resist?

Comment: There are multiple questions here and all of them are more apropos for [Space Exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com/), rather than Astronomy. I recommend investing a little more personal study on these topics. Similar questions have already been asked on Space Exploration, and you might find your answer there already.